# I need help with a summation

Tags: integration, summation

I am studying a mathematical proof of an equation; one of the terms is the following:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^s\sum\limits_{j=s+1}^N\int f\pmb{V}_{ij}\cdot\pmb{n}_{ij} \ d\sigma_{ij} \ d\pmb{\xi}_{j} $$

this quantity is then transformed into this:

$$(N-s)\sum\limits_{i=1}^s \int f\pmb{V}_{i}\cdot\pmb{n}_{i} \ d\sigma_{i} \ d\pmb{\xi}_{*} $$

unfortunately the book where I'm studying from doesn't give much explanation on how this rearrangement is possibile; the only indications given are:

> since $\pmb{\xi}_{j}$ is an integration variable, the sums over $j$ are made up of identical terms; we shall write $\pmb{\xi}_{*}$ in place of $\pmb{\xi}_{j}$ in order to enphasize that the index j is a dummy.

I don't really care much why $\pmb{V}_{ij}$, $\pmb{n}_{ij}$ and $\sigma_{ij}$ become $\pmb{V}_{i}$, $\pmb{n}_{i}$ and $\sigma_{i}$; my only question is: how is it possible that the summation over $j$ becomes $(N-s)$?

Comment: $N-s$ is the number of times you calculate the same integral (the sum ranges from $s+1$ to $N$, i.e. there are $N-s$ terms that are all equals).

Comment: That's what I thought too at first; but then I realized that are always different from each other: let's say that i=1 and I cycle over index j; all the integrals I get are different when i=2 and so on.... where am I mistaken?

Comment: another thing I have noticed: even though j is a dummy, should I have another summation over "*" ?

Comment: If $i$ is fixed, then you can sum over all $j$, and then, for this value of $i$, there are $N-s$ equal integrals (depending of $i$ of course).

Comment: ok and what about $d\pmb{\xi}_{*}$ ? how does the variable know that it needs to assume values from $s+1$ to $N$ every time that $i$ changes?

Comment: I think you may understand $d\xi_{*}$ as any $d\xi_{j}$ : you fix $i$ and $j$ and then integrate with respect to $d\xi_{j}$ . Then, for the same $i$ , you sum over all other $j$ the same integral, i.e. you multiply by the total number of possible $j$ at $i$ fixed, that is $N-s$ . This gives you the same thing that if you consider $N-s$ times the same integral with respect to $d\xi_{*}$. You just note $d\xi_{*}$ to avoid to refer to the $j$ because they are not usefull.